# Unable to clear user data in Google Play Music

Tags: storage, google-play-music, 8.1-oreo, app-data

Google Play music occupies more than 1GB on my mobile phone. As you can see in the screenshot below, User Data accounts for most storage around ~1GB.

When I press the Clear Data button, the screen shows that storage is freed, but the data is there as soon I go back.

I have tried:

1. Clearing Data
2. Clearing Cache
3. Disabling app

My mobile is 10.or D2 and runs Android 8.1.0

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to force stop it before clearing the data? Is the result the same?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Tried it. Results are the same.

Comment: If you can use adb, try `adb shell pm clear com.google.android.music`

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Tried it. It was of no use.

Comment: If possible remove the app. If the app was already installed when you bought the device, try uninstalling the updates, then clear data again.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio There is no option to uninstall the app. I reset my mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the steps mentioned by Reddy Lutonadio in the comments, I performed a factory reset of my device. This solved the issue.